# POST route in Leaflet map giving errors

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, leaflet, mapping

Is there any way to use a form in leaflet mapping to open another page?
I'm using a post route for this and have even tried embedding it in an  tag but to no avail.

At the moment the form data is in a for loop like so

```
 map_data.forEach(element => {

    console.log('program=' + element.program + ', lat=' + element.gps_lat + ', long=' + element.gps_lon);

    data[i] = L.marker([element.gps_lon, element.gps_lat], {icon: redIcon}).addTo(map);

    var url = '{{ route("opentraining", ":training_id") }}';
    var alt_url = '{{ route("opentraining") }}';
    url = url.replace(':id', element.id);
    
    data[i].bindPopup(
        '<strong>' + element.program + '</strong>'
        + '<br />'
        + '<b>Location:</b> ' + element.location + ', ' + element.district + ', ' + element.province
        + '<br />'
        + '<b>Description:</b> ' + element.description
        + '<br /><br />'
        + '<form onsubmit="' + alt_url + '" method="POST" class="formEditTraining">@csrf<input type="hidden" name="training_id" value='+ element.id  + '>'
        + '<button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary trigger-submit">View Record</button>'
        +'</form>'
        ).openPopup();
    i++;
});
```

Even when use the route directly within the form it makes no difference all I get is  an error saying POST method isn't supported.. What could I be missing ?

[image]

Comment: *embedding in an <a> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong attribute for the URL in your `<form>` tag. `onsubmit` is for specifying a JS function to run before the form is submitted. To specify the URL you want to submit the form to, use `action`. Since you are not specifying `action` at the moment, it's posting it back to the same URL that the form is on, which evidently is not set up to receive POSTs.

Comment: Thank you just switched it to action... I tried using this some time ago but with the url variable explicitly stated .. just glad it works now